# Error occurred when passing r-value reference to r-value reference parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference, rvalue-reference, rvalue

I have code

```
void print(string &&str) {
   cout << str << endl;
}
int main() {
   string tmp("Hello");
   string&& str = move(tmp);
   //print(move(str));
   print(str);
   return 0;
}
```

After compiling I get `error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'std::__cxx11::string&&' to lvalue of type 'std::__cxx11::string'`.

But `str` is r-value reference to **r-value**(isn't it?), so passing it into `print` makes sense I believe. Why this error occurred?

Comment: when r-value reference gets a name it looses its r-value reference properties...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing with [value categories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) and types.

(emphasis mine)

> lvalue
>
> The following expressions are lvalue expressions:
>
> - the name of a variable or a function in scope, **regardless of type**, such as std::cin or std::endl. **Even if the variable's type is rvalue
>     reference, the expression consisting of its name is an lvalue
>     expression**;
> - ...

The type of `str` is rvalue-reference (to `string`), but as a named variable it's an lvalue, which can't be bound to rvalue reference.

Consider the following case if this is allowed:

```
string tmp("Hello");
string&& str = move(tmp);
print(str);               // str might be moved here

cout << str << endl;      // dangerous; str's state is undeterminate
```

So you need to use `std::move` *explicitly* (to convert `str` to an xvalue) if you're sure of the effects.